# How to continue marquee after after page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, marquee

I have a marquee and after refreshing page I need to keep my text running not from the beginning.Text should start from the place where it was before I updated my page.Any tips on javascript?

`<marquee direction="left" id="myMarquee" loop="1" >Text here</marquee>`

Edited:ok,thanks guys

Comment: how about don't use a marquee tag after 1995

Comment: `<marquee>` isn't even deprecated, it has become *obsolete* already. This means you really shouldn't use it and opt for a javascript or css based solution instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: there is no way to resume it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marquee tag isn't supported any more, so if you really need this, consider using a javascript solution, for example this plugin

http://download.remysharp.com/marquee.html

For displaying information that needs to grab the visitor's attention, maybe try a different type of layout